# Index Match VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert the following INDEX(),MATCH() function into VBA:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$N$21;MATCH($A24&CHAR(1)&C$23;$A$2:$A$21&CHAR(1)&$B$2:$B$21;0); MATCH($B24;$C$1:$N$1;0))
```

And I found the following set up on StackOverflow:

```
Dim INDEX_ARRAY As Range
Dim INDEX_COLUMN As Range
Dim INDEX_ROW As Range

With Worksheets("Master Scores")
    Set INDEX_ARRAY = .Range(.Cells.Find(iCell.Value).EntireColumn))
    Set INDEX_COLUMN = .Range("A1:A500"))
End With

With Worksheets("EXPORT")
    Set INDEX_ROW = .Range(.Cells(iCell.Row,1))
End WIth

iCell.Formula = Application.Index(INDEX_ARRAY, INDEX_ROW, INDEX_COLUMN)
```

However, I dont know how to convert the `MATCH($A24&CHAR(1)&C$23;$A$2:$A$21&CHAR(1)&$B$2:$B$21;0)` part into the VBA.

I really appreciate your input!

Thanks in advance,

Hieronymus5

Comment: Do you know you can use excel functions directly in VBA code?  You need to write `excel.WorksheetFunction` and then the function you need.  `excel.WorksheetFunction.Match`

Comment: 'Application.WorsheetFunction.'  preceeding an Excel function usually gets what you are after although sometimes, you will have to modify the RANGE format

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone, who had the same question as I did, here's a brilliant piece of VBA code written by Jindon on the Ozgrid forum. Its alot faster than the reference in the cell or worksheetfunction.index / match variant.

```
Sub test() 
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, dic As Object, txt As String 
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
    dic.CompareMode = 1 
    a = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value 
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
        .CompareMode = 1 
        For i = 3 To UBound(a, 1) 
            If Not dic.exists(a(i, 2)) Then dic(a(i, 2)) = Empty 
            For ii = 3 To UBound(a, 2) 
                txt = a(i, 1) & Chr(2) & a(2, ii) 
                If Not .exists(txt) Then 
                    Set .Item(txt) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
                End If 
                .Item(txt)(a(i, 2)) = a(i, ii) 
            Next 
        Next 
        Redim a(1 To .Count + 2, 1 To dic.Count + 2) 
        a(1, 1) = "Code": a(1, 2) = "Variable Code" 
        For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1 
            a(1, i + 3) = dic.keys()(i) 
        Next 
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1 
            a(i + 2, 1) = Split(.keys()(i), Chr(2))(0) 
            a(i + 2, 2) = Split(.keys()(i), Chr(2))(1) 
            For ii = 3 To UBound(a, 2) 
                If .items()(i).exists(a(1, ii)) Then 
                    a(i + 2, ii) = .items()(i)(a(1, ii)) 
                End If 
            Next 
        Next 
    End With 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    With Sheets.Add.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)) 
        .Value = a: .Columns.AutoFit 
    End With 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```